# stop urlRequest onViewDisappear

Tags: swift

I load my json info from my server as follows, but when I click away to a different page too soon, the request keeps trying in the background and there is a warning that the viewController can't be found anymore. How would I cancel all requests onViewDisappear?

```
if let requestURL = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/file.php") {

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "email=\(loginUsername.text!)"
        urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {  (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data {
                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {

                        // Async Stuff
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{

                            // do things
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        })
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Save your requests somewhere and then on moving away from the controller call:

```
task.cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DataCall {
    var task: URLSessionDataTask?

    func load() {
        guard let requestURL = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/file.php") else { return }

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "email=\(loginUsername.text!)"
        urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {  (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data {
                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {

                        // Async Stuff
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{

                            // do things
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func stopTask() {
        task.cancel()
    }
}
```

Then in your `viewWillDissapear` you call `dataCall.stopTask()`.

Comment: Thanx just tried that... and most of the time it works. but after 10-20 tries the request still comes in after the view controller is left and then it crashes. Any ideas why this is happening. Tried exactly what you suggested.

Comment: Could your DispatchQueue move back to main thread end up stuck behind the VC getting dismissed? What I'm thinking is the network request is completed before viewWillDissapear is completed, but after viewWillDissapear is started? Do you have many things happening there?

Comment: What is in your callback? Are you injecting it or is it accessing a global state?

Comment: Im changing background images and UILabelView texts in this view controller when the response comes in. in the main queue... so yes, somehow it most come in after the dismiss starts. this view controller doesnt have any other taks running before and after this request is made.

Comment: then just remove the strong reference and use `[weak self] in` inside your completion call. That would result in your code looking like `self?.myLabel.text = text` inside the completion handler